# Multiple Select group get values

Tags: javascript, html

I have a request form and it contains the select for each User request the available value, I'm having difficulty getting multiple values ​​in select, I can only get 1 value

```
<select id="target" name="mensagem" data-placeholder="Select an option" multiple='multiple' class="form-control">
     <optgroup label="FIRST">
            <option value="{{ Auth::user()->1 }}">{{ Auth::user()->1 }}</option>
            <option  value="{{ Auth::user()->3 }}">{{ Auth::user()->3 }}</option> 
            <option  value="{{ Auth::user()->5 }}">{{ Auth::user()->5 }}</option> 
            <option  value="{{ Auth::user()->7 }}">{{ Auth::user()->7 }}</option> 
            <option  value="{{ Auth::user()->9 }}">{{ Auth::user()->9 }}</option> 
            <option  value="{{ Auth::user()->11 }}">{{ Auth::user()->11 }}</option> 
            <option  value="{{ Auth::user()->13 }}">{{ Auth::user()->13 }}</option> 
       </optgroup>
 </select>

    $('#target').select2();
  $(function(){
        $.fn.select2.amd.require(["optgroup-data", "optgroup-results"], 
            function (OptgroupData, OptgroupResults) {
            $('#target').select2({
                dataAdapter: OptgroupData,
                resultsAdapter: OptgroupResults,
                closeOnSelect: false,

            }); 
        });
    });
```

Comment: Are you unsure if your are using `java` or `php` or is there any other reason to add both those tags?

Comment: Java, Thanks edited

Comment: I don't think I see Java code... is it possible that you mean Javascript?  Particularly jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
<select id="target" name="mensagem" data-placeholder="Select an option" multiple class="form-control">
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but this also did not resolve, still getting only 1 value